# iPhone SDK: how to disable my app sound if playing iPod content?

Tags: iphone, audio, ipod

How can I disable my iPhone app sound if the user is playing iPod content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the correct audio category: [Audio Category](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4). You can simply detect whether the iPod app is playing by handling media player change notifications: [Media Player](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingMediaPlayback/UsingMediaPlayback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH100-SW7).

HTH.